# SQL Server - bulk insert column

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to insert csv file into sql server db.  The problem is I keep getting a

```
 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for
 the specified codepage)  error. this is repeated 10 times and 
 Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error.
The provider did not give any information about the error.
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

The specific column that errors is a bigint,primary key,no null field. I have made sure all 5000 records have a 4 digit number and there are no nulls.  I am tired of fighting this and simply want to insert the date and datavalue fields into this table --CSResult.  The problem is sql server simply errors out and I am thinking it wants values for ALL the fields.
IS there a way to insert data into the columns I want?
Any ideas.

```
     BULK INSERT [DB].[CsSchema].[CsResult] (
     FROM 'c:\june132012.csv'
     WITH
     (
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
     )
```

this is what the data looks like:

```
    3857,2011-05-19 04:00:00.000,Y,,82,N,N,,4,1,1,10,,1,,535/31706815
    3858,2011-05-19 02:23:00.000,Y,,128,N,N,,4,1,1,10,,1,,535/31706815
```

Here is the DDL:

```
    ResultID bigint notnull 
    ResultDate datetime,notnull
    HasValue CHAR 1, notnull 
    Duration int, null 
    DataValue decimal 19,9, notnull 
    IsEdited CHAR 1, notnull 
    IsAnnotated CHAR 1, notnull 
    AddOnValue decimal 19,9, null 
    DataTypeID FK, int, notnull 
    ResultTypeID FK smallint, notnull 
    PatientID FK, int, notnull 
    DataSourceTypeID FK, smallint, notnull 
    MedicationID FK, int, null 
     DataDownloadID FK, int, null 
    SlotTypeID FK,smallint, null 
    DataSourceIdentity nvarchar 20, null
```

Comment: Can you post the table DDL that you're trying to insert into?

Comment: Also have you considered bulk inserting into a staging table with the same columns as your input file, then performing an INSERT/SELECT from there (which may be easier to ignore the other columns)?

Comment: I don't know DDL.  I am just using the bulk insert above. The staging sounds promising. I am new to this but does staging mean create a table with the two columns I want. Then insert the two columns from the newly created staging table into the actual table. correct??

Comment: Wait.Partition means that the data is divided into two. but the software the pulls the data from sql is not configured for that so I don't think that will work.

Comment: By DDL I mean the table create statement. So we can see the columns and their data types.

Comment: here is the data types in the table I want to add data into:

Comment: ``ResultID bigint notnull 
    ResultDate datetime,notnull 
    HasValue CHAR 1, notnull
    Duration int, null
    DataValue decimal 19,9, notnull
    IsEdited CHAR 1, notnull
    IsAnnotated CHAR 1, notnull
    AddOnValue decimal 19,9, null 
    DataTypeID FK, int, notnull
    ResultTypeID FK smallint, notnull
    PatientID FK, int, notnull
    DataSourceTypeID FK, smallint, notnull
    MedicationID FK, int, null
    DataDownloadID FK, int, null
    SlotTypeID FK,smallint, null
    DataSourceIdentity nvarchar 20, null

Comment: @teddy Please add that schema as an edit to your original question instead - it's nigh on impossible to read (and format) in a comment.

Comment: Ah that is the solution then. I couldn't figure out how to make it readable in the comment section.  Please look in the original post for the schema.  Thanks

Comment: Depending on your language/date settings, it might be barfing on `2011-05-19 04:00:00.000` - such strings don't always get converted correctly into datetimes (SQL Server tries to treat the date portion as `yyyy-dd-mm`).

Comment: I don't think I included this in the error msg. The error is on ResultID column and not ResultDate column. I used to get the error on ResultDate but I changed the format into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 in the csv and that error went away.

Comment: I agree with @AaronBertrand Using a staging table is the right way to go. This would allow you to scrub the data better. It is possible you have an invisible character in your identity field. This could be fixed with ` TRIM(field) `